# Call External Service that returns PDF binary stream from C#

Tags: c#

I have a web service (web site) that returns a pdf as a binary file.
You pass in an ID and get the contents of that particular pdf.

Say, for example: http://somesite.com/getPdf?id=12

This works fine.

I would like to call this from my .NET c# program.

I have tried the following, but I seem to be missing something:

```
   private static async Task GetPdf()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "someagent");
            var taskResponse= client.GetAsync("http://somesite.com/getPdf?id=12");

            var msg = await taskResponse;

        }
```

Am I approaching this correctly?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: You're [leaving all your HTTP connections open forever](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/), is that what you think is wrong?

Comment: No, the above code throws an error when executing the await line,  so I'm guessing I'm not invoking the Task correctly.
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
 System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(bool)
 System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(bool)
 ....

Comment: I've tried several variations of the code and I always get a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
 error when executing the await line. I also cannot seem to gracefully catch the exception or check for a null response as VisualStudio itself throws the exception.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the remote url takes a bit of time to return the response. ( perhaps 10 seconds ).

Comment: I suspect whatever is calling `GetPdf` is throwing the error. You need to [debug that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're most likely correct as my call to GetPdf(); did not have the "await" keyword. When I tried to add it though, I got the error the the method that contained that call needed to be marked as async as well  ( which makes sense ). Though the  method is already marked as a [WebMethod] and it doesn't seem to allow you to mark a [WebMethod] as async. I will have to chase that down.